# Listiview error after update get new data

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

**`java.lang.IllegalStateException:`** The content of the `adapter` has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged()

so i'm working with a custom listView when you reach the final of the list i show a footer view  and create a listener to implements on the Activity/Fragment that will use the listView. My problem is when i call a services on this method and update the array with the data of the adapter i received that error. I call too a services on the adapter because i need the data of the specific showing row.

Here go my code:

Custom listView:

```
public class EndlessListView extends ListView implements OnScrollListener {

    private View footer;
    private boolean isLoading;
    private EndlessListener listener;
    private ArrayAdapter<?> adapter;
    private boolean isReachEnd;

    public EndlessListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.setOnScrollListener(this);
    }

    public EndlessListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setOnScrollListener(this);
    }

    public EndlessListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setOnScrollListener(this);
    }

    public void refreshList() {
        this.removeFooterView(footer);
        this.requestLayout();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        isLoading = false;
    }

    public void setListener(EndlessListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        if (getAdapter() == null)
            return;

        if (getAdapter().getCount() == 0)
            return;

        int l = visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItem;
        if (l >= totalItemCount && !isLoading && !isReachEnd) {
            // It is time to add new data. We call the listener
            this.addFooterView(footer);
            this.requestLayout();
            isLoading = true;
            listener.loadData();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }

    public void setLoadingView(int resId) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) super.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        footer = (View) inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        this.addFooterView(footer);

    }

    public void setAdapter(ArrayAdapter<?> adapter) {
        super.setAdapter(adapter);
        this.adapter = adapter;
        this.removeFooterView(footer);
    }

    public void addNewData(ArrayList data) {
        this.removeFooterView(footer);
        this.requestLayout();
        adapter.addAll(data);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        isLoading = false;
    }

    public void removeFooter() {
        if (adapter != null) {
            this.removeFooterView(footer);
            isLoading = false;
            this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            this.requestLayout();
        }
    }

    public void addFooter() {
        if (adapter != null) {
            this.addFooterView(footer);
            isLoading = true;
            this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            this.requestLayout();
        }
    }


    public EndlessListener setListener() {
        return listener;
    }

    public static interface EndlessListener {
        public void loadData();
    }

    public boolean isReachEnd() {
        return isReachEnd;
    }

    public void setReachEnd(boolean isReachEnd) {
        this.isReachEnd = isReachEnd;
    }

    public boolean isLoading() {
        return isLoading;
    }

    public void setLoading(boolean isLoading) {
        this.isLoading = isLoading;
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayAdapter<?> getAdapter() {
        return adapter;
    }

    public View getFooter() {
        return footer;
    }

    @Override
    public void setClickable(boolean clickable) {
        super.setClickable(clickable);
    }}
```

Get data and update the array of the adapter:

```
public void getMatcher() {
    try {
        gettingMatcher = true;
        Timber.i(getString(R.string.getting_mather));
        HomeRequest.createMatcherRequest(getActivity(), new RequestController.ResponseListener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                ((AuthorizedActivity) getActivity()).showProgress(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                parseMatcher(response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int error, String message) {
                gettingMatcher = false;
                ((AuthorizedActivity) getActivity()).showProgress(false);
                Utils.showToast(getActivity(), getString(R.string.error_unexpected));
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        gettingMatcher = false;
        Timber.e(e, getString(R.string.error_getting_matcher));
        Crashlytics.logException(e);
    }
}

/**
 * Parse the data from the web services and load the UI
 *
 * @param response
 */
private void parseMatcher(JSONObject response) {
    MatcherResponse matcherResponse = new MatcherResponse(false, "");
    ArrayList<User> auxDiscover = new ArrayList<>();
    if (response == null) {
        Timber.e(getString(R.string.error_empty_response));
        Utils.showToast(getActivity(), getString(R.string.error_empty_response));
        ((AuthorizedActivity) getActivity()).showProgress(false);
        gettingMatcher = false;
        return;
    }

    try {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
                .create();
        matcherResponse = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), MatcherResponse.class);
        if (matcherResponse.isSuccess()) {
            auxDiscover = matcherResponse.getDiscover();
            if (auxDiscover.size() > 0) {
                discoversData.addAll(auxDiscover);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                discovers.removeFooter();
            }
        } else {
            Timber.e(getString(R.string.error_parsing_matcher));
            Utils.showToast(getActivity(), getString(R.string.error_unexpected));
        }
        gettingMatcher = false;
        ((AuthorizedActivity) getActivity()).showProgress(false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ((AuthorizedActivity) getActivity()).showProgress(false);
        gettingMatcher = false;
        Timber.e(getString(R.string.error_parsing_matcher));
        Crashlytics.logException(e);
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
 public class DiscoverEndlessAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private ArrayList<User> itemList;
    private Context ctx;
    private static OnClickDiscoverEvents onClickDiscoverEvents;
    private DiscoverFragment fragment;

    public DiscoverEndlessAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<User> itemList, OnClickDiscoverEvents onClickDiscoverEvents, DiscoverFragment fragment) {
        super(ctx, R.layout.adapter_discover, itemList);
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.onClickDiscoverEvents = onClickDiscoverEvents;
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public User getItem(int i) {
        return itemList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        return getDiscoverRow(position, convertView, parent, holder);
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        @InjectView(R.id.adapter_discover_title)
        TextView title;
        @InjectView(R.id.adapter_discover_subtitle)
        TextView subTitle;
        @InjectView(R.id.adapter_discover_avatar)
        ImageView avatar;
        @InjectView(R.id.adapter_discover_connect)
        TextView connectWith;
        @InjectView(R.id.adapter_discover_message)
        ImageButton message;
        @InjectView(R.id.adapter_discover_description)
        TextView description;
        @InjectView(R.id.adapter_discover_more)
        ImageButton more;
        @InjectView(R.id.adapter_discover_avatar_connection)
        ImageView avatarConnection;
        @InjectView(R.id.adapter_discover_avatar_connection_2)
        ImageView avatarConnection2;
        @InjectView(R.id.adapter_discover_avatar_connection_3)
        ImageView avatarConnection3;
        @InjectView(R.id.adapter_discover_avatar_connection_4)
        ImageView avatarConnection4;
        @InjectView(R.id.adapter_discover_connection_opacity)
        TextView avatarConnectionOpacity;
        @InjectView(R.id.adapter_discover_message)
        ImageButton messageButton;
        @InjectView(R.id.adapter_discover_more)
        ImageButton optionButton;

        /*OnClick*/
        @OnClick(R.id.adapter_discover_message)
        public void onGoChat(View view) {
            onClickDiscoverEvents.showProfile(view);
        }

        @OnClick(R.id.adapter_discover_more)
        public void onShowMoreOption(View view) {
            onClickDiscoverEvents.showOption(view);
        }

        private Context ctx;

        public ViewHolder(View view, Context ctx) {
            ButterKnife.inject(this, view);
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the view for the chat data row
     *
     * @param position
     * @param convertView
     * @param parent
     * @param holder
     * @return
     */
    private View getDiscoverRow(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, ViewHolder holder) {
        try {
            User user = getItem(position);
            if (convertView != null) {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            } else {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_discover, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder(convertView, ctx);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }

            // Title
            String title = Utils.getNameFromUser(user);
            holder.title.setText(title);

            // Subtitle
            String subTitle = Utils.getRoleAndLocationFromUser(user);
            holder.subTitle.setText(subTitle);

            // Description
            String description = user.getAccomplishment();
            holder.description.setText(description);

            //Avatar
            Utils.setImageToImageViewFromUrl(ctx, holder.avatar, user.getImage(), user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName());

            //ImageButtons
            holder.more.setFocusable(false);
            holder.message.setFocusable(false);

            //CommonConnections
            if (user.getCommonConnections() == null)
                getCommonConnections(user.getId(), position);
            else {
                ArrayList<Connection> connections = user.getCommonConnections();
                if (connections.size() > 0) {
                    if ((connections.size() > 0) && (holder.avatarConnection.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)) {
                        Connection connection = connections.get(0);
                        Utils.setImageToImageViewFromUrl(ctx, holder.avatarConnection, connection.getImage(), connection.getFirstName(), connection.getLastName());
                        holder.avatarConnection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    if ((connections.size() > 1) && (holder.avatarConnection2.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)) {
                        Connection connection = connections.get(1);
                        Utils.setImageToImageViewFromUrl(ctx, holder.avatarConnection2, connection.getImage(), connection.getFirstName(), connection.getLastName());
                        holder.avatarConnection2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    if ((connections.size() > 2) && (holder.avatarConnection3.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)) {
                        Connection connection = connections.get(2);
                        Utils.setImageToImageViewFromUrl(ctx, holder.avatarConnection3, connection.getImage(), connection.getFirstName(), connection.getLastName());
                        holder.avatarConnection3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    if ((connections.size() > 3) && (holder.avatarConnection4.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)) {
                        Connection connection = connections.get(3);
                        Utils.setImageToImageViewFromUrl(ctx, holder.avatarConnection4, connection.getImage(), connection.getFirstName(), connection.getLastName());
                        holder.avatarConnection4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    if ((connections.size() > 4) && (holder.avatarConnectionOpacity.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)) {
                        int quantity = connections.size() - 4;
                        String moreConnections = "+" + quantity;
                        if (quantity > 0) {
                            holder.avatarConnectionOpacity.setText(moreConnections);
                            holder.avatarConnectionOpacity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (isCommon(user.getSkills())) {
                        holder.avatarConnection.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_common_skill);
                    } else
                        holder.avatarConnection.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    if (isCommon(user.getCompanies())) {
                        holder.avatarConnection2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_common_work);
                    } else
                        holder.avatarConnection2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    holder.avatarConnection3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.avatarConnection4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.avatarConnectionOpacity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            //Buttons
            holder.messageButton.setTag(user);
            holder.optionButton.setTag(user);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Timber.e(e, ctx.getString(R.string.error_getview_discover_adapter));
            Crashlytics.log(ctx.getString(R.string.error_getview_discover_adapter));
        }

        return convertView;
    }


    public void getCommonConnections(long caliberId, final int position) {
        try {
            Timber.i(ctx.getString(R.string.getting_common_connections));
            HomeRequest.createCommonConnectionsRequest(ctx, caliberId, new RequestController.
                    ResponseListener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onStart() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    parseCommonConnections(response, position);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(int error, String message) {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.error_unexpected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Timber.e(e, ctx.getString(R.string.error_getting_common_connections));
            Crashlytics.logException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Parse the data from the web services and load the UI
     *
     * @param response
     */
    private void parseCommonConnections(JSONObject response, int position) {
        CommonConnectionsResponse commonConnectionsResponse = new CommonConnectionsResponse();
        ArrayList<Connection> connections = new ArrayList<>();
        if (response == null) {
            Timber.e(ctx.getString(R.string.error_empty_response));
            return;
        }

        try {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
                    .create();
            commonConnectionsResponse = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), CommonConnectionsResponse.class);
            if (commonConnectionsResponse.isSuccess()) {
                itemList.get(position).setCommonConnections(commonConnectionsResponse.getConnections().getConnections());
                fragment.discoversData.get(position).setCommonConnections(commonConnectionsResponse.getConnections().getConnections());
            } else {
                itemList.get(position).setCommonConnections(new ArrayList<Connection>());
                fragment.discoversData.get(position).setCommonConnections(new ArrayList<Connection>());
                Timber.i(ctx.getString(R.string.no_common_connections, Utils.getNameFromUser(fragment.discoversData.get(position))));
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Timber.e(ctx.getString(R.string.error_parsing_common_connections));
            Crashlytics.logException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return common value of skill or company object from list
     *
     * @param list
     * @return
     */
    private boolean isCommon(ArrayList<?> list) {
        if ((list != null) && (list.size() > 0)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                Object object = list.get(i);
                if (object instanceof Skill) {
                    if (((Skill) object).isCommon())
                        return true;
                } else if (object instanceof Company) {
                    if (((Company) object).isCommon())
                        return true;
                } else
                    return false;
            }
        } else
            return false;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call setAdapter(null) before modifying data inside the Adapter.